# Sending voice data over UDP using Wi-Fi IP address

Tags: java, android, coronasdk

I want to use Wi-Fi ip address of the audio data between two mobile phone transmission and reception using the UDP.

However, the voice data is not coming
I wonder what the problem is in the code below

```
package com.example.audio;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.*;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class ReadAudio implements Runnable{
    public AudioRecord record;
    public int bufferSize;
    byte [] sendData;
    InetAddress addr;
    DatagramSocket sendDs;
    DatagramPacket sendDp;

    public void run(){
        sendData = new byte[bufferSize];
        bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        record = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, 8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize);
        record.startRecording();

        try{
            addr = InetAddress.getByName("Wi-Fi ip Number");
            sendDs = new DatagramSocket();

            while(true){
                record.read(sendData, 0, bufferSize);
                sendDp = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, addr, 18763);
                sendDs.send(sendDp);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class PlayAudio implements Runnable{
    public AudioTrack track;
    byte [] gdata;
    byte [][] getdata;
    int bufferSize;
    InetAddress addr;
    DatagramSocket getDs;
    DatagramPacket getDp;

    public void run(){
        bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, 8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
        getdata = new byte[16][bufferSize];
        gdata = new byte[bufferSize];

        int i,j,k, portNumber;
        i = 0;
        j = 0;
        k = 0;
        portNumber = 18763;

        try{
            addr = InetAddress.getByName("Wi-Fi ip Number");
            getDs = new DatagramSocket(portNumber, addr);
            while(true){
                getDp = new DatagramPacket(gdata, gdata.length);
                getDs.receive(getDp);
                getdata[i] = getDp.getData();

                if(i == 8){
                    j = i;
                }
                if(j == 8){
                    track.write(getdata[k], 0, bufferSize);
                    track.play();
                }
                if(++i == 16){
                    i = 0;
                }
                if(++k == 16){
                    k = 0;
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button startButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ReadAudio ra = new ReadAudio();
                PlayAudio pa = new PlayAudio();

                Thread RA = new Thread(ra);
                Thread PA = new Thread(pa);

                RA.start();
                PA.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```